# How to compare user's input with value from a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm asking a user to put in a string which is supposed to be a meaning of the word in the key of the dictionary 9it's in another language). How can I compare it to the value of the very same key?
This is my piece of code:

```
slownik ={

   "我":"ja",
    "你":"ty",
    "他":"on"
}
for key in slownik:
    print ('Do you know the meaning of this character', key, '?')
    podane_znaczenie = input ('Meaning: ')
    if podane_znaczenie == _______:
        print ('Yes!')
        continue
```

Comment: show some code for as as orientation

Comment: Please add this to the question and read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to ask on our site. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, key-value pairs can be treated as tuples. This lets you iterate through a dictionary in a very handy way:

```
for key, value in my_dict:
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Using this method, we can fill in the missing space in your code like this:

```
for key, value in slownik:
    print ('Do you know the meaning of this character', key, '?')
    podane_znaczenie = input ('Meaning: ')
    if podane_znaczenie == value:
        print ('Yes!')
        continue
```

Furthermore, while you didn't ask for this exactly, the `continue` statement is not needed in this code snippet. Because there is no more code after it, the loop will continue on its own :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need the value of the dict

```
if podane_znaczenie == slownik[key]:
```

You could also write it as

```
for key, value in slownik.items():
    print ('Do you know the meaning of this character', key, '?')
    podane_znaczenie = input ('Meaning: ')
    if podane_znaczenie == value:
        print ('Yes!')
        continue
```

PS: `continue` is not needed here

Answer (score 0):

You access the values of dictionarys with`dictname[key]`, so in your code it would be

```
if podane_znaczenie == slownik[key]:
    print ('Yes!')
```